# Como puedo eliminar el autofirmado en tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas Tardes.

Me marca este error al revisar la pagina con www.whynopadlock.com

Answer (score 0):

No es cuestión de configuración de Tomcat, es cuestión del certificado. Necesitas que te lo firme una *Certificate Authority* (CA). Una certificado firmado por una CA significa que la CA asegura que los datos del certificado son correctos (por ejemplo, que tú eres el dueño del dominio y no alguien que ha suplantado el servidor).

El procedimiento técnico es sencillo, creas un *Certificate Signing Request* (csr) con tu certificado y con la CA lo firmas. Hay montones de ejemplos en la web. La cuestión es qué CA usas para firmar.

Tu puedes crear tu propia CA y firmar tu certificado. El problema es que cuando un cliente conecte por HTTPS, recibirá un certificado que dice "Este servidor es servidordedavidleal.com. Lo asegura una CA en la que no confiamos". Así que lógicamente, no se fiará del certificado.

En una intranet, puedes intentar usar tu propia CA y hacer que en los equipos tu CA esté reconocida como de confianza, y no tendrás el problema. Para internet, lo que toca es buscar CAs que ya estén instaladas en los navegadores y pedirles que te firmen el certificado; puede que te obliguen a seguir determinados pasos para verificar que realmente eres el dueño del servidor.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.Estoy usando certificados de godaddy, pero me quedo en ese error y no se como sulucionarlo